# Копия возвращаемая structuredClone не равна оригиналу при сравнении через isDeepStrictEqual

Tags: javascript, node.js

Имеется следующий код:

```
const util = require('util');

function A() {}
let obj = {
    key: new A()
};
let copy = structuredClone(obj);
console.log(util.isDeepStrictEqual(obj, copy));
```

Я ожидаю получить в консоль true, но получаю false. В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что клонирование не сохраняет прототипы, а `isDeepStrictEqual` их сравнивает.

В клоне `copy.key` это объект типа `Object`, а не `A`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#things_that_dont_work_with_structured_clone

> The prototype chain is not walked or duplicated.

https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertdeepstrictequalactual-expected-message

> `[[Prototype]]` of objects are compared using the `===` operator.